# erase certain portion of a image on a canvas using touch events in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am developing an app.

I upload an image on a html 5 canvas.

I need to trim certain areas of this image.

In canvas.addlistener touchevents, that acts as a brush tool to draw an arc in white color. So that white background is achieved.

```
function drawDot(ctx,x1,y1){
    ctx.fillStyle="#ffffff";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1,y1,15,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
 }
```

I tried the above code, but not working... used line tool and all modes of compositeoperation.

Is there any restriction on the type of image such as transparent image?

Pl help

Comment: Would you give an example of this in a snippet of fiddle so we can see what's going wrong? Also does it work with the default value of `globalCompositeOperation`?

Comment: Please, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: My app details: I am setting up my garden

1. upload my_lawn image in canvas A 
2. crop certain portion of lawn image using jCrop , (get crop region - crop_width,crop_height)
3.Upload plant image (width and height of this sized to crop_width and crop_height) in canvas B
4 Overlay                                                                                       In canvas C, I put canvas B img on to canvas A img
ctx.putImageData(imgData1,0,0) - Canvas A img
ctx.putImageData(imgData2,x,y) - canvas B img

rest of the steps in my next comment

Comment: 5 : Though x,y are almost ok, I try to positon it perfectly by moving imgData2 on imgData1. through touchevent  
6: Save canvas C  and the img is saved as imgData3
7 Place imgData3 on new canvas D (The image now I have is lawn on which some plant image)
8:  In canvas D, erase certain portions using touchevents on imgdata3
Step 8 is not working.                                                                                                       
Can I not use addlistener for two canvases on a single page?
I tried composting, arc,line but nothing seems to work.I upload some random jpg gif files